# Syntax error: Non-declaration statement outside function body, but everything there is declaration

Tags: go

This doesn't work:

```
package main

var formatter string = "fmt"

import (
    formatter
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(formatter)
}
```

I got: `syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body`

Even though everything there is declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [Go specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Source_file_organization):

> Each source file consists of a package clause defining the package to
> which it belongs, followed by a possibly empty set of import
> declarations that declare packages whose contents it wishes to use,
> followed by a possibly empty set of declarations of functions, types,
> variables, and constants.
>
> ```
> SourceFile       = PackageClause ";" { ImportDecl ";" } { TopLevelDecl ";" } .
> ```

This means that top-level declarations such as `var formatter string = "fmt"`  must come *after* any import declarations, if any import declarations are present. Technically, you're getting this error because the definition of [declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope) does not include import declarations (despite the name), and your source code has an import declaration after a top-level declaration, where an import declaration is not allowed to be.

Furthermore, the [Import declarations section](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations) shows that import paths must be string literals, so even if it weren't for the ordering issue, you still wouldn't be able to do what you're attempting.